# Twitter Bootstrap does not play well with Firefox

Tags: firefox, twitter-bootstrap, firebug

I am using Twitter bootstrap on a MeteorJS app. When I run it on Firefox, I got many errors like:

```
Expected declaration but found '*'. Skipped to next declaration.
*margin-left: 62.28677941443899%;
bootstrap...db5283e (line 311, col 6)
```

In Bootstrap, I have:

```
 .row-fluid .offset4 {
margin-left: 36.75213675213675%;
*margin-left: 36.645753773413354%;
}
```

I would like to know why this happens and I can avoid this warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the CSS the line with the asterisk at the beginning is saying that for IE7 and below use this rule.

It's a hack which is only understood by IE7 and below.

I wouldn't worry about the error as it shows as an error on all bootstrap official CSS files and won't do any harm afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you really wanted to pass CSS verification in most major browsers, and you'd have a weekend to spare, you could write a separate IE stylesheet.

I wonder whether the folks at bootstrap have already though of that?